# how to modify the movement speed of a standard asset(thirdpersoncharacter) using other scripts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets

I have a problem here in my project. I am currently using the standard asset Third Person Character.

## In this script, everything is provided except for the sprinting of the character. i have provided the script below.

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class ThirdPersonCharacter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float m_MovingTurnSpeed = 360;
    [SerializeField] float m_StationaryTurnSpeed = 180;
    [SerializeField] float m_JumpPower = 12f;
    [Range(1f, 4f)][SerializeField] float m_GravityMultiplier = 2f;
    [SerializeField] float m_RunCycleLegOffset = 0.2f; //specific to the character in sample assets, will need to be modified to work with others
    [SerializeField] float m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
    [SerializeField] float m_AnimSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
    [SerializeField] float m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;
    Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
    Animator m_Animator;
    bool m_IsGrounded;
    float m_OrigGroundCheckDistance;
    const float k_Half = 0.5f;
    float m_TurnAmount;
    float m_ForwardAmount;
    Vector3 m_GroundNormal;
    float m_CapsuleHeight;
    Vector3 m_CapsuleCenter;
    CapsuleCollider m_Capsule;
    bool m_Crouching;


    void Start()
    {
        m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        m_Capsule = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
        m_CapsuleHeight = m_Capsule.height;
        m_CapsuleCenter = m_Capsule.center;

        m_Rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationY | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationZ;
        m_OrigGroundCheckDistance = m_GroundCheckDistance;
    }


    public void Move(Vector3 move, bool crouch, bool jump)
    {

        // convert the world relative moveInput vector into a local-relative
        // turn amount and forward amount required to head in the desired
        // direction.
        if (move.magnitude > 1f) move.Normalize();
        move = transform.InverseTransformDirection(move);
        CheckGroundStatus();
        move = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(move, m_GroundNormal);
        m_TurnAmount = Mathf.Atan2(move.x, move.z);
        m_ForwardAmount = move.z;

        ApplyExtraTurnRotation();

        // control and velocity handling is different when grounded and airborne:
        if (m_IsGrounded)
        {
            HandleGroundedMovement(crouch, jump);
        }
        else
        {
            HandleAirborneMovement();
        }

        ScaleCapsuleForCrouching(crouch);
        PreventStandingInLowHeadroom();

        // send input and other state parameters to the animator
        UpdateAnimator(move);
    }


    void ScaleCapsuleForCrouching(bool crouch)
    {
        if (m_IsGrounded && crouch)
        {
            if (m_Crouching) return;
            m_Capsule.height = m_Capsule.height / 2f;
            m_Capsule.center = m_Capsule.center / 2f;
            m_Crouching = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Ray crouchRay = new Ray(m_Rigidbody.position + Vector3.up * m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, Vector3.up);
            float crouchRayLength = m_CapsuleHeight - m_Capsule.radius * k_Half;
            if (Physics.SphereCast(crouchRay, m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, crouchRayLength, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
            {
                m_Crouching = true;
                return;
            }
            m_Capsule.height = m_CapsuleHeight;
            m_Capsule.center = m_CapsuleCenter;
            m_Crouching = false;
        }
    }

    void PreventStandingInLowHeadroom()
    {
        // prevent standing up in crouch-only zones
        if (!m_Crouching)
        {
            Ray crouchRay = new Ray(m_Rigidbody.position + Vector3.up * m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, Vector3.up);
            float crouchRayLength = m_CapsuleHeight - m_Capsule.radius * k_Half;
            if (Physics.SphereCast(crouchRay, m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, crouchRayLength, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
            {
                m_Crouching = true;
            }
        }
    }


    void UpdateAnimator(Vector3 move)
    {
        // update the animator parameters
        m_Animator.SetFloat("Forward", m_ForwardAmount, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
        m_Animator.SetFloat("Turn", m_TurnAmount, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
        m_Animator.SetBool("Crouch", m_Crouching);
        m_Animator.SetBool("OnGround", m_IsGrounded);
        if (!m_IsGrounded)
        {
            m_Animator.SetFloat("Jump", m_Rigidbody.velocity.y);
        }

        // calculate which leg is behind, so as to leave that leg trailing in the jump animation
        // (This code is reliant on the specific run cycle offset in our animations,
        // and assumes one leg passes the other at the normalized clip times of 0.0 and 0.5)
        float runCycle =
            Mathf.Repeat(
                m_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime + m_RunCycleLegOffset, 1);
        float jumpLeg = (runCycle < k_Half ? 1 : -1) * m_ForwardAmount;
        if (m_IsGrounded)
        {
            m_Animator.SetFloat("JumpLeg", jumpLeg);
        }

        // the anim speed multiplier allows the overall speed of walking/running to be tweaked in the inspector,
        // which affects the movement speed because of the root motion.
        if (m_IsGrounded && move.magnitude > 0)
        {
            m_Animator.speed = m_AnimSpeedMultiplier;
        }
        else
        {
            // don't use that while airborne
            m_Animator.speed = 1;
        }
    }


    void HandleAirborneMovement()
    {
        // apply extra gravity from multiplier:
        Vector3 extraGravityForce = (Physics.gravity * m_GravityMultiplier) - Physics.gravity;
        m_Rigidbody.AddForce(extraGravityForce);

        m_GroundCheckDistance = m_Rigidbody.velocity.y < 0 ? m_OrigGroundCheckDistance : 0.01f;
    }


    void HandleGroundedMovement(bool crouch, bool jump)
    {
        // check whether conditions are right to allow a jump:
        if (jump && !crouch && m_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Grounded"))
        {
            // jump!
            m_Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(m_Rigidbody.velocity.x, m_JumpPower, m_Rigidbody.velocity.z);
            m_IsGrounded = false;
            m_Animator.applyRootMotion = false;
            m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;
        }
    }

    void ApplyExtraTurnRotation()
    {
        // help the character turn faster (this is in addition to root rotation in the animation)
        float turnSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(m_StationaryTurnSpeed, m_MovingTurnSpeed, m_ForwardAmount);
        transform.Rotate(0, m_TurnAmount * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }


    public void OnAnimatorMove()
    {
        // we implement this function to override the default root motion.
        // this allows us to modify the positional speed before it's applied.
        if (m_IsGrounded && Time.deltaTime > 0)
        {
            Vector3 v = (m_Animator.deltaPosition * m_MoveSpeedMultiplier) / Time.deltaTime;

            // we preserve the existing y part of the current velocity.
            v.y = m_Rigidbody.velocity.y;
            m_Rigidbody.velocity = v;
        }
    }


    void CheckGroundStatus()
    {
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
```

## if UNITY_EDITOR

```
        // helper to visualise the ground check ray in the scene view
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f) + (Vector3.down * m_GroundCheckDistance));
```

## endif

```
        // 0.1f is a small offset to start the ray from inside the character
        // it is also good to note that the transform position in the sample assets is at the base of the character
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), Vector3.down, out hitInfo, m_GroundCheckDistance))
        {
            m_GroundNormal = hitInfo.normal;
            m_IsGrounded = true;
            m_Animator.applyRootMotion = true;
        }
        else
        {
            m_IsGrounded = false;
            m_GroundNormal = Vector3.up;
            m_Animator.applyRootMotion = false;
        }
    }
}
```

## }

I would like to override/change the characters MOVEMENT SPEED(using different script) depending on these instances:
-When pressing shift as sprint(partly solved but i would like to see other solutions since what i did is override it using
the main script and its not appropriate in my game since i have alot of instances and i want it in  a different script)
-When colliding with Buffs/debuffs(stun/slow/boost speed etc)(overriding the default MovementSpeed temporarily in n-seconds)
-When the character is wearing an item with stats(overriding the default MovementSpeed)

OR if you have some assets with basic animations and third person controller that is easier to use and to modify, i'd appreciate it if you can give me a link!

Please help me. this is my thesis project and i only have a really limited time (since self studying from the start ate up my time). I am currently stuck in this part of coding. THANK YOU!

Comment: The answer in the duplicate should show you how to change CC speed. Otherwise let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: sorry but it does not work and somehow it has a different logic. what i need here is to access it using other scripts and add sprint + buff/debuffs effects